# Naming choice in Java -- clone vs. copy

Tags: java, language-design, history

We have "**copy** constructor" but "**clone** method". This asymmetry in naming puzzles me -- does anyone know for what reason the method was not named "copy" (and interface per analogy "Copyable")?

*This question is about **historical** process of Java language design, and the choice that was made, not current opinion which one is "better".*

Comment: "copy constructor" is overwhelmingly C++ jargon, not Java jargon. Are you sure you'll get a meaningful answer from that community?

Comment: @KilianFoth, C++ is older than Java, so when the design process began this term was already present. Anyway, if the dice were not involved, any choice had a reason -- and I want to find out one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kilian Foth already pointed out in [his comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/305106/1352#comment638737_305106), the term *copy constructor* is primarily if not exclusively used in C++. C++ had little to no impact on the design of Java, except in a "how *not* to do it" way.

[The primary influence on Java is Objective-C](https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html), where this method is also called `clone`. Objective-C inherited this terminology from Smalltalk, where the method is again called `clone`. Objective-C is contemporary to C++, Smalltalk predates it. So, the question should rather be: why did C++ introduce this asymmetry in the first place?